# How to write Junit for CDK stage

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, aws-cdk

I am newbie in cdk. I have requirement to create the SQS infra on deployment.
For that following is piece of code and its works fine in env.

```
export class TestStage extends cdk.Stage {
  
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: TestProps) {
    super(scope, id);

    const stgStack = new cdk.Stack(this, 'TestStage', {
      description: 'This test environment.',
    });

    let list: string[] = data.sqs;

    list.forEach(queueName => {
      let sqsId = 'CreateSQS_' + queueName;
       const queue = new TestPattern(stgStack, sqsId, queueName);
       console.log(sqsQueue);
    });
  }
}
```

Now I want to write the unit test for this so that before executing code in env I can make sure things are good. Following is unit test code where I want to verify newly created sqs is added in stage or not.
But don't know I can I do that.

```
test('Test Stage ', () => {

const app = new App();

let testStage = new TestStage (app, 'test-stage', {
  desc: "test"  
});

const testSqsStage = new Stack(testStage, 'TestStack');

const template = Template.fromStack(testSqsStage);
console.log(testSqsStage);

});
```

can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to verify newly created sqs is added in stage or not

```js
// Assert the expected number of Queues:
template.resourceCountIs('AWS::SQS::Queue', data.sqs.length);
```